# How do I create a global Array that increases in size in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-coder

I would like to create a global array within a Matlab function block in Simulink that grows in size, each time the Matlab function block is called. The only approach to create global variables in a Matlab function block is to link it to a "Data Store Memeory" block but this does not allow me to create arrays which increase in size.

I am currently using a local array within the Matlab function block and writing the contents of the array to a file before exiting the function block and reading from it in the next iteration. This slows down the execution time though. Is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a persistent variable in a function to store the data. Place the following function in a file `varsizeDataStore.m` on your MATLAB path:

```
function y = varsizeDataStore(varargin)
%#codegen
% Update the bounds to fit your needs
coder.varsize('p',[1,2000], [0,1]);
persistent p;
if isempty(p)
    p = zeros(1,0);
end

if nargin > 0
    p = [p, varargin{1}];
end

y = p;
```

When you want to grow the persistent variable, pass a parameter to `varsizeDataStore`. To query the value call it with no parameters.

Obviously, you can change the logic in`varsizeDataStore` to suit your needs. Its purpose is to demonstrate the idea of using a persistent variable and a function as a way to store and query data without using a global variable.